# How do I derive physical path of a relative directory inside Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to set up Weceem using the source from GitHub.  It requires a physical path definition for the uploads directory, and for a directory for appears to be used for writing searchable indexes. The default setting for uploads is:

```
weceem.upload.dir = 'file:/var/www/weceem.org/uploads/'
```

I would like to define those using relative paths like WEB-INF/resources/uploads.  I tried a methodology I have used previously for accessing directories with relative path like this:

```
  File uploadDirectory = ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource("WEB-INF/resources/uploads").file
  def absoluteUploadDirectory = uploadDirectory.absolutePath
  weceem.upload.dir = 'file:'+absoluteUploadDirectory
```

However, 'parentContext' under ApplicationHolder.application is NULL.  Can anyone offer a solution to this that would allow me to use relative paths?

Comment: For what it is worth, I have also attempted to do:


`File uploadDirectory = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getParentContext().getResource("resources/uploads").getFile()`


But again, "Cannot invoke method getParentContext() on null object"

Answer (score 3):

look at your Config.groovy you should have (maybe it is commented)

```
// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config
// config files can either be Java properties files or ConfigSlurper scripts

// "classpath:${appName}-config.properties", "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
grails.config.locations = [
        "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
        "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"
]
```

Create Conig file in deployment server

```
"${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties"
```

And define your prop (even not relative path) in that config file.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Aram Arabyan's response, which is correct, but lacks an explanation:

Grails apps don't have a "local" directory, like a PHP app would have. They should be (for production) deployed in a servlet container. The location of that content is should not be considered writable, as it can get wiped out on the next deployment.

In short: think of your deployed application as a compiled binary.

Instead, choose a specific location somewhere on your server for the uploads to live, preferably outside the web server's path, so they can't be accessed directly.  That's why Weceem defaults to a custom folder under `/var/www/weceem.org/`.

If you configure a path using the [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) technique, you can then have a path specific to the server, and include a *different* path on your development machine.

In both cases, however, you should use absolute paths, or at least paths relative to known directories.

Comment: This makes sense, but I am trying to determine how I would apply this to an app that is deployed to SaaS like CloudBees when you have no idea what the physical directory structure is, and even more certainly don't have permissions to write to most of it.  Do you have any thoughts on how something like Weceem could be used with a service like that?  I honestly don't have any intentions of allowing uploads, so just filling that in with /foo/bar might suffices for my needs, but assuming I did want to use that functionality, do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you are deplaying to a cloud service (you really should have mentioned that!), you usually won't have access to anything but temporary storage.  The correct solution is to use a dedicated service, like Amazon S3, to store files.  I don't know Weceem, so I don't know if that is even possible.  Also, the searchable indexes issue is a known problem, and can be difficult to solve when in that kid of environment.

Answer (score 0):

i.e.

```
            String base = System.properties['base.dir']     
            println "config: ${base}/web-app/config/HookConfig.grooy"
            String str = new File("${base}/web-app/config/HookConfig.groovy").text
            return new ConfigSlurper().parse(str)
```

or

```
def grailsApplication    
private getConfig() {
            String str = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("config/HookConfig.groovy").file.text
            return new ConfigSlurper().parse(str)
}
```